# Sed error : bad option in substitution expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a configuration file (`gpsd.default`) containing data with the following format:

```
# If you must specify a non-NMEA driver, uncomment and modify the next line     
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"                                                
GPSD_OPTIONS=""                                                                
GPS_DEVICES=""
```

I am making a change on the file with sed:

```
sed -i 's/^GPS_DEVICES="".*/GPS_DEVICES="dev/ttyUSB1"/' /etc/default/gpsd.default
or 
sed -i '4s/^.*/GPS_DEVICES="dev/ttyUSB1"/' /etc/default/gpsd.default
```

The above `sed` command returns error:

> sed: bad option in substitution expression

Because the new line contains "`/`" in its expression.

How to update my `sed` command to make it work?

Comment: The `/` isn't your only potential problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460

Answer (score 43):

This is because you are using a regex containing `/`, which is the same character `sed` uses as delimiter.

Just change the `sed` delimiter to another one, for example `~`:

```
sed -i 's~^GPS_DEVICES="".*~GPS_DEVICES="dev/ttyUSB1"~' /etc/default/gpsd.default
```

By the way, since you are changing files in `/etc`, you may want to use `-i.bak`, so that the original file gets backed up. It is a good practice to prevent loss of important information.

Comment: It is practice if it is being used as a noun :)

Comment: @fedorqui You could just escape the `/ `like `\/`

Comment: @Jahid yes, true, but it is neater to use another delimiter.

Comment: For this particular case, yeah, but what would you do if you wanted to match `~` ?

Comment: @Jahid there is no definitive solution for this. Neither escaping nor using another delimiter solves all the situations, so it is a matter to see what suits best in each case.

Answer (score 4):

You should update your sed command to this.

```
sed -i 's/^GPS_DEVICES=\"\".*/GPS_DEVICES=\"dev\/ttyUSB1\"/' /etc/default/gpsd.default
```